# How to get around Unity games having trouble with rendering text for in game HUD

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple 2D Unity Game for Android, and in there I have some text in a canvas that overlays the game play which serves as a heads up display. I've noticed when the text is triggered to change the game has a significant frame rate drop, it looks like a stutter when playing. Why is such a simple task is so demanding, and more importantly how can I get around this?

Comment: You should provide some code and a better explanation of what happens, as it is now the question is too broad to answer it.

Comment: @Galandil this is a common problem with rendering text over gameplay, there is not much that is unique to my situation, I am just wondering is there a way around this

Answer (score 0):

When you use the new Unity UI System this kind of task becomes much more fluid and dosent stutter or lag anymore. I can recomend you to switch to the new ui system instead of rendering text without it